# Autowiring fails IllegalArgument un-safe operation exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am getting the following exception after upgrading my Spring jars.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed  
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#4': Cannot create inner bean     '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher$MessageProcessingHeaderValueMessageProcessor] while setting constructor argument with key [#{partnerHeaderKey}]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.data.dao.PartnerDAO field com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.PartnerHeaderEnricher.partnerDAO to org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher$MessageProcessingHeaderValueMessageProcessor
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValue Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.data.dao.PartnerDAO field com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.PartnerHeaderEnricher.partnerDAO to org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher$MessageProcessingHeaderValueMessageProcessor
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.data.dao.PartnerDAO field com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.PartnerHeaderEnricher.partnerDAO to org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher$MessageProcessingHeaderValueMessageProcessor
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
... 44 more
```

From what I have read I needed to add `@Component` annotation to my bean and/or create the  in my application context - neither of these approaches have worked. The DAO  it is referring to is declared like so `<bean id="partnerDAO" class="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.data.dao.impl.PartnerDAOImpl"/>`. If I remove the `@Component` annotation I get a red line under `@Autowired` and a message that says "Autowired members must be defined in the valid spring bean (@Component/@Service etc..)", but after doing that i still get the errors.

I am using Spring integration so the bean to auto-wire is defined there.

```
<integration:header-enricher>
        <integration:header name="#{partnerHeaderKey}" method="getPartner">
            <bean class="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.PartnerHeaderEnricher"/>
        </integration:header>
    </integration:header-enricher>
```

Any thoughts or help is appreciated! Thank you.

**Note**: the application runs fine if I drop back down to Spring 2.1.4.RELEASE even without declaring the `@Component` or `<bean>` in the application context.

**UPDATE**

As blackpanther mentions below I need a  element in the application context. I failed to mention that I DO Have this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher" />` There is another for the DAO's as well `<context:component-scan base-package="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.data.dao" />`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, just putting the annotation `@Component` does not mean that that Java class will have it's properties autowired. In order to use the `@Component` annotation effectively, you must tell Spring where to look for these classes. This is done by the `<context:component-scan base-package="package.name" />` tag in your Spring configuration.

I would have a look at this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/) as it may help you.

Comment: Yes, I do have this tag as well. I apologize for not mentioning it. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify @Qualifier on top of the bean declaration inside the component like below.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("loginService")
private ILoginService loginService;
```

loginService is the name of the bean in the .xml context file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using @Component annotation as well as modifying the way the beans were created in the context.

For some reason when I moved the `<bean class="">` out of the `<integration:header>` and added a `ref-""` attribute it started working just fine. I am getting a different error, but I was able to get the application running.

*old way*

```
<integration:header-enricher>
    <integration:header name="#{partnerHeaderKey}" method="getPartner">
        <bean   class="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.Partner    HeaderEnricher"/>
    </integration:header>
</integration:header-enricher>
```

*new way*

```
<integration:header-enricher>
<integration:header name="#{partnerHeaderKey}" method="getPartner" ref="myBean">
</integration:header>
    </integration:header-enricher>
</integration:chain>
<bean id="myBean"   class="com.follett.fheg.coursemateriallookup.coursematerial.integration.headerenricher.PartnerHeaderEnricher"/>
```